# Shell script for loop error: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")

Tags: shell

So I realize others have asked similar questions in the past, but when I tried their solutions (using dos2unix, and checking vim for extraneous symbols), they didn't work at all.

```
#!/bin/bash
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
mainDir=/mnt/data1/sam
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
cd $fastqDir
for i in `ls *R1_001.fastq.gz`
do
#----------------------------------
 filename="${i%_R1_001.fastq.gz}"
#---------------------------------- 
    #adapter-trim
#---------------------------------- 
 echo "Alignment started for $filename" >> ${qcDir}/${filename}_report.txt

 filename="${i%_R1_001.fastq.gz}"
 echo $filename

 echo "Alignment started for $filename" >> ${qcDir}/${filename}_report.txt
 sed '/chrM/d;/chrY/d;/random/d;/chrUn/d' < Aligned.out.sam | samtools view -bS -F 4 -q 30 -u - | samtools sort - > ${bamDir}/${filename}.bam 
 rm Aligned.out.sam
 mv Log.final.out ${qcDir}/${filename}_STARLogFinal.txt 

 echo "Picard started for $filename" >> ${qcDir}/${filename}_report.txt
 mv ${bamDir}/${filename}_dedup.bam ${bamDir}/${filename}.bam 
 samtools index ${bamDir}/${filename}.bam 

 echo "Picard insert size histogram for $filename" >> ${qcDir}/${filename}_report.txt
 INSERT_TXT_FILE="${qcDir}/${filename}.insertSizes.txt"
 INSERT_HISTO_FILE="${qcDir}/${filename}.insertSizes.pdf"

 echo "Making bigwig for $filename"
    lines=$(samtools view -c ${bamDir}/${filename}.bam);\
    bedtools genomecov -ibam ${bamDir}/${filename}.bam -bg -scale $(echo "1000000 / ${lines} " | bc -l) -g ${RefDir}/${genome}.chrom.sizes | \
    wigToBigWig -clip stdin ${RefDir}/${genome}.chrom.sizes ${bwDir}/${filename}.bw 2> $tmpDir/${filename}_log

 echo "macs2 for $filename"
done
```

I keep getting error

```
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

Sorry if this question is kind of silly, I'm completely new to shell scripting.

Comment: As an aside -- you shouldn't be using `ls` here. The proper way to iterate over files is `for i in *R1_001.fastq.gz; do`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: The other thing is that your code right now is missing multiple elements of the [mcve] definition -- it's not minimal (includes a lot of stuff unnecessary to get the bug), but it's also not complete or verifiable (since it doesn't complete your `for` loop syntax by including a `done` at the end).

Comment: As another aside -- there's no reason at all to check if a directory exists before running `mkdir` on it; just use the `-p` argument to make a directory that already exists nonfatal. If you just run `mkdir -p --
 "$bamDir"/{bw,macs,qc,tmp}`, then that's just one line replacing most of your script.

Comment: OK, editing it right now. Sorry new to shell, so don't really know how the code works.

Comment: And always, *always* check whether `cd` succeeded or failed before continuing to the rest of your script -- otherwise you can run code in the wrong directory when something unexpected happens. `cd -- "$fastqDir" || exit` will do the job. (The `--` as a separate argument is just a bit of extra paranoia -- makes sure `"$fastqDir"` is parsed as a directory name even if it starts with a dash).

Comment: Being new to shell, I'd strongly suggest making a habit of running code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- that'll give you a lot of feedback.

Comment: OK, thanks so much!

Comment: okay, so now this is complete, but it's not minimal. If you take stuff other than the echo out from the loop, do you still get the same error? Basically, try to work towards the smallest code sample that still exhibits the same error when tested.

Comment: Yes, I do. Editing it again.

Comment: There is no shebang.  Which shell are you using the execute this script?

Comment: There's no need for a continuation character on the newline after a pipe symbol.  If you end the line with `|`, it automatically continues.  As a point of style, however, it is more usual to write `cmd1 \ ` on one line, followed by `| cmd2` on the next line.  (Putting the pipe symbol at the start of the line makes it more obvious to the reader.)

Comment: Thanks! Also I'm using bash, I just forgot to copy over the shebang into this site.

Comment: For the specific error you're giving, this really *does* look like a nonprintable character, as much as you're asserting having checked for that condition. That said, to provide a byte-for-byte copy, to allow 3rd-party verification -- could you run `base64 < yourscript | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us`, and provide the resulting link here?

Comment: http://sprunge.us/XieO

Comment: You're right. So sorry about this. I ran a command to delete extraneous characters (even though I can't find any in vim) and the script started working afterwards. Thanks so much for the help! In the future, what is the correct way to find extraneous characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be extraneous characters after all. I ran the following command and the script started working afterwards. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the help everyone!

```
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < file-with-binary-chars > clean-file
```

Comment: That's funny -- it implies that the copy you uploaded to sprunge isn't the same one having the problem, since the output of running the copy on sprunge through `tr` has the exact same md5sum as the input.